# Regex which contains only numbers and some characters

Tags: php, regex, validation

I need regex which contains only 0-9 numbers and the following characters: -,+,# (but not required)

How should this be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about `([0-9]|[\-+#])+`?

Comment: Why not combine them into one character class?  `/^[0-9+#-]*$/` (for matching) and `/([0-9+#-]+)/` for capturing ?

Comment: @ircmaxell: Hmmm good question. This was the first thing that came to mind, but I suppose having them in one class should work too.

Comment: @Brad: No that's not as easily understandable as ircmaxell's answer (though it would probably work just as well).

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: Fair enough.  I was just curious more than anything (there's nothing "wrong" with your method).  +1

Comment: I tend to escape out characters for the sake of eliminating influence on the pattern. And Maybe I'm wrong, but I believe the hyphen needs to be escaped (`\-`) (unless it's exempt when it's the last character in the list)

Comment: This /^[0-9+#-]*$/ return this
warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '^' in ...

Comment: @Toktik: No it doesn't.  It works quite fine for me...  @Brad: It needs to be escaped unless it's the first or last character in the class, or it's completely unambiguous what it means (it's still better to escape inside of the class)

Comment: @Brad your method worked, but it's passed when the string contains at least one character from that list. I need string which contains ONLY that characters.

Comment: @ircmaxwell: So I see, good to know. I tend to just escape anything for both safety and clarity. ;-) @Toktik, you need to wrap it with `/^` & `$/` to bind the pattern to the beginning and end of the string, respectfully. `/^[0-9\x2D\x2B\x23]+$/`

Answer (score 7):

This should work with what you're looking for

```
/[0-9+#-]/
```

fixed as per comment below

Comment: It's sloppy to put the `-` character in the middle of the regex.  While it may work, it can be confusing.  It's [recommended](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php) to put it at the end of the class (`[0-9+#-]`)...